# azure web app deployment in django not working

Tags: django, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

When I deploy my django app in azure with sql database, it is showing me `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred`.

But when I deploy it without sql database it works fine. What is the problem?

error log

Most likely causes:

```
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
```

Comment: Would you please check the trace log on Kudu then post it here? In addition, what's the version of django you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed. I deploy my django app to azure with sqlserver database by using [django-mssql](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) successfully.

Please refer to the steps I did:

Step 1: Add configuration in **settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '***',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': '***.database.windows.net',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
            'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True'
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add test code to query results:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ***")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

Step 3: Install `django-mssql` package and dependency on KUDU.

[image]

Step 4: Deploy django app to azure and access url in browser.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

---

**Update Answer:**

Firstly , the error as below when you tried to build django with django-mssql because your version of django is too high.

[image]

From the [django-mssql doc](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation) , you could see : `Django 1.8 is supported by the current release` and your django version is `1.11.8`.

Secondly, the `django-pyodbc` package which you mentioned in your comment just supports `django 1.10`. You could refer to this [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc).

So, I suggest you to use [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) package which supports `django 1.11` by now.

You could follow the tutorial in above doc.

Configuration in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '***',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '***.database.windows.net',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

My django version is as same as you and it works for me.

[image]

Any concern please let me know.

---

Update Answer2 :

I just used Visual Studio 2017 python django template.

My **view.py** :

```
"""
Definition of views.
"""

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.student")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def about(request):
    row = my_custom_sql()
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        {
            'title': row,
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

Please note the `my_custom_sql()` function.

My **about.html**:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}.</h2>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>

<p>Test Something!</p>

{% endblock %}
```

And the `pyodbc` settings in the **`settings.py`** just refer to my previous update answer.

Comment: thank you for your help but the engine is not working in my machine and also in azure

Comment: @Robel You followed my steps then the error you mentioned in your post occurred?

Comment: when i use "sqlserver_ado" engine it is showing me this error     self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable but with "sql_server.pyodbc" it works in my machine not in azure

Comment: @Robel Ah,I also met the error :TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.The reason is your django release is too high or django-mssql's dependent packages missing.

Comment: File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 78, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
2018-01-23 13:33:40.095000: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 closed

Comment: @Robel it's django-mssql or django-pyodbc?

Comment: it is django-pyodbc

Comment: @Robel what's your django version?

Comment: i am using  django==1.11.8

Comment: @Robel Hi,Robel. Any updates now? I used pyodbc and it works for me.

Comment: can you send me your code i am getting in to a lot of problems Thank you

Comment: thank you  i solve the above problem but i run in to another problem File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)
ValueError: "Djangoapp.wsgi.application" could not be imported
2018-01-30 11:49:10.463000: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 closed

Comment: thank you  i solve the above problem but i run in to another problem

Comment: @Robel Would you please offer your web.config file , you could post it in your question?

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\activate_this.py" />
    
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="DjangoApp.settings" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.get_virtualenv_handler()"/>

Answer (score 0):

Please enable [Diagnostics Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for debugging your application and determine the real cause of your application is not working. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/07/14/troubleshoot-logging-python-application-errors-on-azure-webapi-apps/) blog post may also help you troubleshooting-logging your application.